# How can I add strings to a list based on the user's input?

Tags: python-2.x

Im trying to add a function that allows the user to type their own quote, and add it into a list. I just dont know the code and cant seem to find an explanation anywhere.

Ive tried this: Useradd = raw_input("whats your quote")
my_quotelist.append("")

the my_quotelist.append("") is for whatever the user types to be added to the list.

```
 elif UserQuoteAdd_str in addquote_list:

UserQuoteAdd_str = raw_input("What is your quote?")
```

Answer (score 0):

Create the list, assuming it doesn't already exist:

```
quotes = []
```

Get the user input:

```
userInput = raw_input("what's your quote? ")
```

Add the user input to the list:

```
quotes.append(userInput)
```

This is what you get in the `python -i` console:

```
>>> quotes = []
>>> userInput = raw_input("what's your quote? ")
what's your quote? hi im andrew
>>> quotes.append(userInput)
>>> print(quotes)
['hi im andrew']
```

Comment: is there also a way i can save it? I want to be able to store it and be accessable whenever the program is ran.

Comment: @amerivi welcome to stack overflow. it's customary to accept an answer rather than piling more questions on. you can of course ask another question!